# What is the function in the code executing

Tags: c, linux

I found the below code online

```
void main(void)
{
  ((void(*)()) "\xeb\x11\x59\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xd2\xb0\x04\xb3\x01\xb2\x36\xcd\x80\xeb\xf6\xe8\xea\xff\xff\xff\x48\x6f\x6c\x62\x65\x72\x74\x6f\x6e\x20\x3c\x33\x20\x40\x6b\x61\x6c\x6f\x75\x30\x30\x30\x20\x2b\x20\x40\x67\x61\x6e\x64\x69\x62\x61\x72\x20\x2b\x20\x40\x53\x74\x65\x70\x68\x61\x6e\x47\x61\x6e\x64\x69\x20\x3a\x29\x0a")();
}
```

Compiling and running this code is continuously printing the following:

```
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
```

Can you please tell how is this working?

I have compiled this with -m32 flag. Looking at strace output it is continuously calling write system call

```
write(1, "Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandib"..., 54Holberton <3 @kalou000 + @gandibar + @StephanGandi :)
```

Comment: I'd suggest writing those raw bytes to a file, then disassembling it. Assuming it's not doubly-obfuscated, they're probably the compiled form of a function. Note that DEP (data execution protection) should be preventing this from working...

Comment: How can we generate such code and what is DEP?

Comment: Compiling this and running this was unsafe. I recommend not to do that again with anything remotely similar. You have allowed arbitrary code to be executed on your system.

Comment: DEP: google "data execution prevention".

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: @Yunnosch It ain't that much unsafer than your average C program...

Comment: @Lundin The average completly non-understood C program yes. But a C program consisting only of basic-parameterized printfs and a loop - I feel noticably safer with than this "Dare to execute me?" code.

Comment: It's allowed to print anything because `void main` is undefined behavior. Okay, ducking under the table now!

Answer (score 1):

in c you can do incredible things. this is one of them.

you see a simple buffer but this is not. it is a machine code represented in hex-string.

this buffer cast to void function and then it called.

`"\xeb\x11\x59\x31\xc0..."` is a function body in machine code and when it cast to `(void(*)())` it became a function in code and then called by `();`

in c you can cast any to any. when the compiler sees `();`, assembles a jump instruction to the first byte and then let CPU execute the rest.

that is how it works.

Comment: Please note however, that casting from a string literal to a function pointer is wildly undefined behavior. These kind of things are _not_ made available from C, but from non-standard extensions in the form of quality of compiler implementation. And even if you have that, calling convention hiccups may occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to become a master of such kind of programs you can check the [ioccc competition](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ioccc%20competition&atb=v209-4&ia=web).

In the code you pasted you convert a pointer from object into a pointer to function and you jump with the execution at the address of the object.  At that location there is the data from the string object.  You inserted in that string data that actually represents code.

To see what that code represents, I inserted it into a disassembler, see [here](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly2):

```
Disassembly
Raw Hex (zero bytes in bold):

EB115931C031DB31D2B004B301B236CD80EBF6E8EAFFFFFF486F6C626572746F6E203C3320406B616C6F75303030202B204067616E6469626172202B20405374657068616E47616E6469203A290A   

String Literal:

"\xEB\x11\x59\x31\xC0\x31\xDB\x31\xD2\xB0\x04\xB3\x01\xB2\x36\xCD\x80\xEB\xF6\xE8\xEA\xFF\xFF\xFF\x48\x6F\x6C\x62\x65\x72\x74\x6F\x6E\x20\x3C\x33\x20\x40\x6B\x61\x6C\x6F\x75\x30\x30\x30\x20\x2B\x20\x40\x67\x61\x6E\x64\x69\x62\x61\x72\x20\x2B\x20\x40\x53\x74\x65\x70\x68\x61\x6E\x47\x61\x6E\x64\x69\x20\x3A\x29\x0A"

Array Literal:

{ 0xEB, 0x11, 0x59, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x31, 0xDB, 0x31, 0xD2, 0xB0, 0x04, 0xB3, 0x01, 0xB2, 0x36, 0xCD, 0x80, 0xEB, 0xF6, 0xE8, 0xEA, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x48, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x62, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x3C, 0x33, 0x20, 0x40, 0x6B, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x75, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x20, 0x2B, 0x20, 0x40, 0x67, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x69, 0x62, 0x61, 0x72, 0x20, 0x2B, 0x20, 0x40, 0x53, 0x74, 0x65, 0x70, 0x68, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x47, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x69, 0x20, 0x3A, 0x29, 0x0A }

Disassembly:
0:  eb 11                   jmp    0x13
2:  59                      pop    ecx
3:  31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
5:  31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
7:  31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
9:  b0 04                   mov    al,0x4
b:  b3 01                   mov    bl,0x1
d:  b2 36                   mov    dl,0x36
f:  cd 80                   int    0x80
11: eb f6                   jmp    0x9
13: e8 ea ff ff ff          call   0x2
18: 48                      dec    eax
19: 6f                      outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[esi]
1a: 6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[edi],dx
1b: 62 65 72                bound  esp,QWORD PTR [ebp+0x72]
1e: 74 6f                   je     0x8f
20: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
21: 20 3c 33                and    BYTE PTR [ebx+esi*1],bh
24: 20 40 6b                and    BYTE PTR [eax+0x6b],al
27: 61                      popa
28: 6c                      ins    BYTE PTR es:[edi],dx
29: 6f                      outs   dx,DWORD PTR ds:[esi]
2a: 75 30                   jne    0x5c
2c: 30 30                   xor    BYTE PTR [eax],dh
2e: 20 2b                   and    BYTE PTR [ebx],ch
30: 20 40 67                and    BYTE PTR [eax+0x67],al
33: 61                      popa
34: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
35: 64 69 62 61 72 20 2b    imul   esp,DWORD PTR fs:[edx+0x61],0x202b2072
3c: 20
3d: 40                      inc    eax
3e: 53                      push   ebx
3f: 74 65                   je     0xa6
41: 70 68                   jo     0xab
43: 61                      popa
44: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
45: 47                      inc    edi
46: 61                      popa
47: 6e                      outs   dx,BYTE PTR ds:[esi]
48: 64                      fs
49: 69                      .byte 0x69
4a: 20 3a                   and    BYTE PTR [edx],bh
4c: 29 0a                   sub    DWORD PTR [edx],ecx
```

This kind of code is not portable.

C language, by allowing this kind of constructs, is an example of [homoiconic language](https://wiki.c2.com/?HomoiconicLanguages) -- a language in which is valid the paradigm "code is data and data is code" (there is no distinction between code and data).  If you program in lisp-like languages this kind of programming is very common.  In C it is however rarely used.